# How can I use PL Sql in Hive using Spark?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

```
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)

val s = hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM Test")
```

But don't know how to use PL SQL in hive. Please help me.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Test` is not PL/SQL but plain SQL.

Comment: yes its not pl sql . I dnt know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to use PL/SQL code in hivecontext.sql() as it requires a querystring and not procedure.
The method returns a new data frame and would not perform operations as usually done in an PL/SQL code.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.html

Comment: Is there any way to do procedure format in hive using Spark

Answer (score 0):

It appears [the answer is "yes"](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59690156), which I found in about 20 seconds by googling "hive spark pl/sql". And it has a [reference manual here](http://www.hplsql.org/doc)

> HPL/SQL is an open source tool (Apache License 2.0) that implements
> procedural SQL language for Apache Hive, **SparkSQL**, Impala as well as
> any other SQL-on-Hadoop implementation, any NoSQL and any RDBMS.
>
> HPL/SQL is a hybrid and heterogeneous language that understands
> syntaxes and semantics of almost any existing procedural SQL dialect,
> and you can use with any database, for example, running existing
> Oracle PL/SQL code on Apache Hive and Microsoft SQL Server, or running
> Transact-SQL on Oracle, Cloudera Impala or Amazon Redshift.
>
> HPL/SQL
> language is compatible to a large extent with Oracle PL/SQL, ANSI/ISO
> SQL/PSM (IBM DB2, MySQL, Teradata i.e), PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL (Netezza),
> Transact-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase) that allows you
> leveraging existing SQL/DWH skills and familiar approach to implement
> data warehouse solutions on Hadoop. It also facilitates migration of
> existing business logic to Hadoop. HPL/SQL is an efficient way to
> implement ETL processes in Hadoop

.

Comment: sparksql 1.6.1 isn't compatible with hive 2.0 which provides HQL (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#compatibility-with-apache-hive)

Comment: Thanks. Pity. Have Spark announced plans to support later Hive versions?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not aware of any JIRA concerning hive 2.0 integration in spark. They are working on spark 2.0 now, so it might take a while.